# Prevent text selection from <button> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

In my HTML I have a button located in a div:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

The *Close* text is being copied when users **double-click** my *url-output* div. Which can be seen here:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="url-output"></div>
</div>
```

Relevant Javascript below. Full JS can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/L4n5q2Te).

```
$('#url-output').text("http://url.domain.me/" + data.shortID);
```

So essentially, if the *url-output* text was something like "www.google.com", the copied text would read:

> *www.google.com*
>
> *Close*

I've attempted several solutions, such as disabling pointer events, and the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css). But I'm having no luck.

How can I exclude the *Close* text from my output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the button text via a pseudo element either using `:before` or `:after` to disable the selection.

```css
.my-button:before {
  content: "Close";
}
```

```html
Example <button class="my-button"></button>
```

If you need it to have a better accessibility, use `.sr-only` class that is built-in with Bootstrap. This works if there isn't any text after the button.

```css
.my-button:before {
  content: "Close";
}

/* http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
Example <button class="my-button"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```